# Why is one expression ambiguous and the other not?

Tags: swift, reduce, ambiguous

The following code works

```
let evens = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7].reduce(Set<Int>()) { (var set: Set<Int>, int: Int) -> Set<Int> in

        if (true) {

        set.insert(int)

        }

    }
```

...but the compiler thinks this is ambiguous?

```
let evens = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7].reduce(Set<Int>()) { (var set: Set<Int>, int: Int) -> Set<Int> in

        set.insert(int)

    }
```

Bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code works

No, it doesn't:

```
:; swift
"crashlog" and "save_crashlog" command installed, use the "--help" option for detailed help
"malloc_info", "ptr_refs", "cstr_refs", and "objc_refs" commands have been installed, use the "--help" options on these commands for detailed help.
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1 (700.1.101.6 700.1.76). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let evens = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7].reduce(Set<Int>()) { (var set: Set<Int>, int: Int) -> Set<Int> in 
  2.  
  3.         if (true) { 
  4.  
  5.         set.insert(int) 
  6.  
  7.         } 
  8.  
  9. }   
evens: Set<Int> = {}
repl.swift:9:1: error: missing return in a closure expected to return 'Set<Int>'
}
^
```

In both cases, the problem is that you haven't returned anything, but you need to return something of type `Set<Int>`:

```
let evens = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7].reduce(Set<Int>()) { (var set: Set<Int>, int: Int) -> Set<Int> in
    if (true) {
        set.insert(int)
    }
    return set
}
```

```
let evens = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7].reduce(Set<Int>()) { (var set: Set<Int>, int: Int) -> Set<Int> in
    set.insert(int)
    return set
}
```

Comment: Sorry, by "works" I meant I didn't get that ambiguous error. Can't believe I forgot to return...Thanks